# Hibernate HBM Mapping Problem

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hbm

I have the following three classes:

```
public class Student {
    private Integer studentId;
    private StudentSchool studentSchool;
    private School school;

    public Integer getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }
    public void setStudentId(Integer studentId) {
        this.studentId = studentId;
    }
    public StudentSchool getStudentSchool() {
        return studentSchool;
    }
    public School getSchool() {
        return school;
    }
    public void setSchool(School school) {
        this.school = school;
    }
}

public class StudentSchool {
    private Student student;
    private School school;  

    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
    public School getSchool() {
        return school;
    }
    public void setSchool(School school) {
        this.school = school;
    }
}

public class School {
    private Integer schoolId;
    private Set allStudents;

    public Integer getSchoolId() {
        return schoolId;
    }
    public void setSchoolId(Integer schoolId) {
        this.schoolId = schoolId;
    }
    public Set getAllStudents() {
        return allStudents;
    }
    public void setAllStudents(Set allStudents) {
        this.allStudents = allStudents;
    }
}
```

I have the following DDL:

```
create table Student (StudentId Integer);
create table StudentSchool (SchoolId Integer, StudentId Integer);
create table School (SchoolId Integer Primary Key);
```

I have the following HBM files:

School.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="School" table="School">
        <property name="schoolId" type="integer" />
        <set name="allStudents" table="StudentSchool" fetch="join">
            <key column="schoolId" />
            <composite-element class="StudentSchool">
                <parent name="school"/>
                <many-to-one name="student" column="studentId" not-null="true" class="Student" />
            </composite-element>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Student.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Student" table="Student">
        <property name="studentId" type="integer" />
        <one-to-one name="studentSchool" class="StudentSchool" />
        <!-- <one-to-one name="school" class="School" /> -->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to query the Student object based on the school, I get the following exception (even though I have a class called "StudentSchool" compiled in my classpath):

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: persistent class not known: StudentSchool
```

If I uncomment the one-to-one mapping to "School" and comment out the one-to-one mapping to "studentSchool", I get the following exception:

```
<AST>:1:143: unexpected AST node: : java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what I did wrong with my hbm mapping? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should give the fully qualified name of your classes in the hbm files.

like somepackage.StudentSchool

EDIT: If all are in the same package, then try adding this

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Student" table="Student">
        <property name="studentId" type="integer" />
        <one-to-one name="studentSchool" class="StudentSchool" property-ref="student"/>
        <!-- <one-to-one name="school" class="School" property-ref="student"/> -->
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Well, in my example, there is no fully qualified name. The Student, StudentSchool, and School classes are in the default package.